# Laravel Collection::paginate does not exist

Tags: laravel, methods, eloquent, pagination

I am trying to paginate Model result, but I am getting "Method paginate does not exist.". Here is my code :

```
$etablissements = Etablissement::where('slug', $slug)->firstOrFail();
$faculty = $etablissements->filieres->paginate(5);
```

I need to recover all the faculties of the school. It works very well without the paginate method

Comment: `$etablissements->filieres` returns a Collection, which doesn't have a `paginate()` method. `$etablissements->filieres()` returns a Builder instance, which does, so `$etablissements->filieres()->paginate(5)` should work.

Comment: No problem! Gotta be aware of what you're working with when using Laravel relationships  Collection and Builder classes share a lot of functions (like `where()`, etc.), but not `paginate()`. Sidenote, voted to close as syntax error/typo/non-reproducible (there's no harm/penalty for a close question, just housekeeping)